# No route matches {:controller=>"stocks", :action=>"create"} RSpec Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message when I run RSpec:

```
Failure/Error: post :create
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"stocks", :action=>"create"}
```

The controller stocks exists, the action create exists, and the route it should be using is this:

```
match 'stocks/:user_id' => 'stocks#create', :via => :post, :as => :query
```

Route File:

```
FruthScreener::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'stocks#index' # add user_id
match 'stocks/:user_id' => 'stocks#create', :via => :post, :as => :query
match 'stocks/:user_id' => 'stocks#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :reset
match 'stocks/:user_id/update' => "stocks#update_index", :via => :post
```

Stock Controller: (Yes, this will be DRYed up)

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
def index
    @user = User.create
    @user_id_num = @user.id
    @user.stocks = Stock.all
    @user.save
    selected_user_stocks = (UserStock.where("user_id = #{@user_id_num} AND selected = true")).take(25)
    @stocks = UserStock.convert_to_stocks(selected_user_stocks)
    @pages = Pagination.determine_num_pages(@user.stocks) 
end

def update_index
    @user_id_num = params[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(@user_id_num)
    selected_user_stocks = UserStock.where("user_id = #{@user_id_num} AND selected = true")
    @stocks = UserStock.convert_to_stocks(selected_user_stocks)
    @pages = Pagination.determine_num_pages(@stocks)
    @stocks = Stock.display(@stocks, params[:pageNumber].to_i)
    render partial: 'stock_data'
end

def create
    UserStock.eliminate_stocks(params) # thinking it's like "creating" a new batch of stocks
    @user_id_num = params[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(@user_id_num)
    selected_user_stocks = UserStock.where("user_id = #{@user_id_num} AND selected = true")
    @stocks = UserStock.convert_to_stocks(selected_user_stocks)
    @pages = Pagination.determine_num_pages(@stocks) 
    @stocks = Stock.display(@stocks, 1)
    render partial: 'stock_data'
end

def destroy
    stocks_to_reset = UserStock.where("user_id = #{params[:user_id]}")
    stocks_to_reset.each do |user_stock|
        user_stock.selected = true
        user_stock.save
    end
    @user_id_num = params[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(@user_id_num)
     selected_user_stocks = UserStock.where("user_id = #{@user_id_num} AND selected = true")
    @stocks = UserStock.convert_to_stocks(selected_user_stocks)
    @pages = Pagination.determine_num_pages(@stocks) 
    @stocks = Stock.display(@stocks, 1)
    render partial: 'stock_data'
end


end
```

Stock Controller Spec: (test at bottom is failing)

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end

describe StocksController do

  context "index" do 
    before do 
        @user_count = User.all.count 
        @stock_count = Stock.all.count
        get :index
    end

    it "should create a new user" do
        expect(User.all.count).to eq(@user_count + 1)
    end

    it "should associate all stocks with the user" do
        expect(User.last.stocks.count).to eq(@stock_count)
    end
  end

  context "create" do # investigate why this isn't working...
    it "should render the stock_list partial" do
        user = User.create
        post :create
        response.should render_template(partial: "stock_list")
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
match 'stocks/:user_id' => 'stocks#create', :via => :post, :as => :query
```

tells us that it needs :user_id to be a valid route.

```
post :create
```

has no :user_id... so it doesn't refer to a valid route.
I'd change it to

```
post :create, :user_id => user.id
```

Comment: so simple yet brilliant - i had the exact problem!

Comment: This produces a deprecation warning in Rails 5: `DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::TestCase HTTP request methods will accept only keyword arguments in future Rails versions.` The proper syntax would now be: `post :create, params: { user_id: user.id }`

Comment: Thanks for updating it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
post :create, params: {user_id: user.id}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit what this code does, how it should be used and why it solves the problem?

Comment: As you can see in the route match .    'stocks/:user_id' => 'stocks#create' expects user_id before it routes to the action. So user_id needs to be passed in the params.